# Efficient way to compare values and generate new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to compare values from each row with valid values (separate list) and if row value doesn't match with valid values,then raise an error message.

I am able to generate output, what I want. But, I feel that is not at all efficient way to do it.

My Attempt-

```
set.seed(1234)
dt <- data.frame(a_check=c(20,2,1,NA,0),
                 b_check=c(0,1,NA,1,15))    

valid_values <- list(a_check= c(1,2,3), b_check= c(0,1))
param_names <- colnames(dt)

error_msg <- list()
error <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {      
  for(j in 1:length(param_names)) {
    if(is.na(match(as.character(unlist(dt[param_names[j]]))[i], as.character(unlist(valid_values[j]))))) {
      error_msg[j] <- paste0(toupper(param_names[j]), " must be one of the following values ", paste(unlist(valid_values[j]), collapse = '-'))

    } else {
      error_msg[j] <- NA
    }
  }
  error[i] <- paste(unlist(error_msg), collapse = " & ")
}

final_error <- unlist(error)
dt$error <- final_error
```

My Output:

```
> dt
  a_check b_check                                                                                               error
1      20       0                                              A_CHECK must be one of the following values 1-2-3 & NA
2       2       1                                                                                             NA & NA
3       1      NA                                                NA & B_CHECK must be one of the following values 0-1
4      NA       1                                              A_CHECK must be one of the following values 1-2-3 & NA
5       0      15 A_CHECK must be one of the following values 1-2-3 & B_CHECK must be one of the following values 0-1
```

**Note-** I exactly want, what I am getting, but, I don't want `NA & NA` and also no `NA &`. Its easy to do this for 2 variables. But, I have more than 500 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` you could do it in a more vectorised manner. Looping though columns but not rows:

```
> dt <- as.data.table(dt)

> dt[,  paste0(param_names, "_test") := lapply(param_names, function(x){
    get(x, dt) %in% get(x, valid_values)
})]


   a_check b_check a_check_test b_check_test
1:      20       0        FALSE         TRUE
2:       2       1         TRUE         TRUE
3:       1      NA         TRUE        FALSE
4:      NA       1        FALSE         TRUE
5:       0      15        FALSE        FALSE
```

**EDIT:** Assigning answer to one column:

```
library(magrittr)

dt[,  wrong_cols := lapply(param_names, function(x) {
    (!(get(x, dt) %in% get(x, valid_values))) %>%
      ifelse(., x, "")
  }) %>% Reduce(paste, .)]

> dt
   a_check b_check      wrong_cols
1:      20       0        a_check 
2:       2       1                
3:       1      NA         b_check
4:      NA       1        a_check 
5:       0      15 a_check b_check
```

**EDIT_2**

```
dt[, error := lapply(param_names, function(x) {
  ((get(x, dt) %in% get(x, valid_values))) %>%
    ifelse(., " ", paste(x, "should have valid values like -", paste(get(x, valid_values), collapse = " ")))
}) %>% Reduce(paste, .)]

> dt
   a_check b_check                                                                                     error
1:      20       0                                            a_check should have valid values like - 1 2 3 
2:       2       1                                                                                          
3:       1      NA                                               b_check should have valid values like - 0 1
4:      NA       1                                            a_check should have valid values like - 1 2 3 
5:       0      15 a_check should have valid values like - 1 2 3 b_check should have valid values like - 0 1
```

Comment: But, as I have 500 columns, it will be difficult to keep track of  500 Boolean columns to generate error column.

Comment: @Rushabh You don't have to have separate columns, you can assign them to one with `Reduce`. `magrittr` used just to keep code easier to read. Similarly you can add `must be one of the following values 1-2-3` inside `ifelse` if required

Comment: thats very clean and helpful!

Comment: I have tried adding `valid values 1-2-3` inside `ifelse`, but it prints one by one. I am writing something like this `dt[,  error := lapply(param_names, function(x) {
    (!(get(x, dt) %in% get(x, valid_value))) %>%
      ifelse(., paste0(x, "should have valid values like - ",get(x,valid_value)), "")
  }) %>% Reduce(paste, .)]`

Comment: @Rushabh its because `get(x, valid_value)` is a vector, you can collapse it to single with `paste(x, collapse = " ")`. See edit. But to be honest, it can be cleaned even more. Right now it has too many get and paste calls...

Comment: Wow, this seems to be more cleaner. I am beginner and learning. So, don't mind for basic questions.

Answer (score 2):

add a check column to your df and have a go at the `%in%` `?match` function maybe with `ifelse` for `TRUE|FALSE` results ...

i like @Jav 's answer, if you add just a reshape on top (more precisely before) of it you can have all the information in just two columns, `merge`(i.e. join) it with your error lookup table and and later reshape it back to wide

example reshape:

```
dt_long <- reshape(data = dt,  times = names(dt),
               direction = 'long', timevar = "type", 
               varying = list(names(dt)), idvar = "id", v.names = "values")
```

Comment: You should not be using for loops in R - since you mentioned > 500 variables. That's why I suggested you vectorize and then later assign the error messages you find useful. you are just repeating the same paste function every time in the for loop, so adding no useful information there. Just merge the error messages at the end to your result dataframe => and rememeber: try to vervtorize

Comment: sure. I know, it is not efficient, and my question says itself. I tried different ways to achieve this. but, appending error message for each value becomes difficult. It would be helpful, if you can provide any efficient working code.

Comment: give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

This works as well. It is a little more concise / efficient. I can check with `microbenchmark` later but it looks like your issue is already resolved.

```
dt <- data.frame(a_check=c(20,2,1,NA,0),
                 b_check=c(0,1,NA,1,15))

valid_values <- list(a_check= c(1,2,3), b_check= c(0,1))


dt_errors <- sapply(1:ncol(dt), function(x) ifelse(!dt[[x]] %in% valid_values[[x]],
                                                   paste0(toupper(names(dt)[x]), 
                                                          " must be one of the following values: ", 
                                                          paste(valid_values[[x]], collapse = ", ")), 
                                                   ""))

dt$error <- apply(dt_errors, 1 , paste, collapse = " & ")
dt$error <- trimws(gsub("^ &|& $", "", dt$error))
dt
  a_check b_check                                                                                                    error
1      20       0                                                     A_CHECK must be one of the following values: 1, 2, 3
2       2       1                                                                                                         
3       1      NA                                                        B_CHECK must be one of the following values: 0, 1
4      NA       1                                                     A_CHECK must be one of the following values: 1, 2, 3
5       0      15 A_CHECK must be one of the following values: 1, 2, 3 & B_CHECK must be one of the following values: 0, 1
```

EDIT: actually, you may have to adjust the regex pattern if there are more than two variables to remove the extra `&`'s. Otherwise, it should scale well.

Adding another `gsub` statement should do the trick (in theory).

```
dt$error <- apply(dt_errors, 1 , paste, collapse = " & ")    
dt$error <- gsub("( & )\\1+", "\\1", dt$error)
dt$error <- gsub("^ & | & $", "", dt$error)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

compose_err_msg <- function(col)
  paste(toupper(col), 
        "must be one of the following values", 
        paste(valid_values[[col]], collapse = "-"))

dt$error <- 
  dt %>% 
  imap(~ ifelse(
    .x %in% valid_values[[.y]],
    list(character(0)),
    list(compose_err_msg(.y))
  )) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  map(lift(str_c, sep = " & ")) %>% 
  map_chr(~ if (identical(., character(0))) "" else .)

#   a_check b_check                                                                                               error
# 1      20       0                                                   A_CHECK must be one of the following values 1-2-3
# 2       2       1                                                                                                    
# 3       1      NA                                                     B_CHECK must be one of the following values 0-1
# 4      NA       1                                                   A_CHECK must be one of the following values 1-2-3
# 5       0      15 A_CHECK must be one of the following values 1-2-3 & B_CHECK must be one of the following values 0-1
```

Note that I don't claim this is is a more efficient or simpler way to do it. There is obviously a lot going on here.

The key is `imap()` that loops over columns (the `.x` variable) and their names at the same time (`.y`).

The not so important part is using `stringr::str_c` instead of `paste` to answer the constraint of no `"NA & NA"`. This adds extra complexity with the need to use `character(0)` and ultimately replace it with `""`.